# GitHub action label is not able to match

Tags: java, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to run some steps based on labels below is the step I'm using

```
      - name: Check PR labels action
        id: pr-label
        uses: shioyang/check-pr-labels-on-push-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          labels: '["security"]'
```

and in the GitHub I have created label "security" but when I create PR with this(security) label above step is not working and in the debug it is printing steps.pr-label.outputs.result='false' what is the issue with my configuration and have no idea what does secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN  do in the secrets I have not defined GITHUB_TOKEN but for other repo it works without GITHUB_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

`GITHUB_TOKEN` is create automatically by GitHub - you don't have to define it anywhere, so it's not the problem for sure.

When you look deeper into the action - it also uses `github.context.sha` and pulls only PRs for given SHA - so my guess is you are not creating PR that is connected to the SHA that is used to trigger workflow - if you update full workflow and show me PR that you expect to see there - I will be able to confirm that.